# What does it mean when R, S values begin with zeroes?

Tags: transactions, signature, wallet-import-format

I was hired to fix some typos in a WIF but I went into analyzing transactions instead then I found 3 R values that begin like this:

```
008505
008391
00a542
```

Then 2 S values begin like this:

```
S: 00db19
S: 00d050
```

So I'm wondering what does it really mean, is nonce biased and partially calculable since I already have partial private key, or is it just nothing?

Comment: I’m confused. R, S appear in signatures, but a wallet would import private keys or addresses. Could you perhaps provide more background on what you’re trying to do?

Comment: @Murch Yes, I am asking about signatures and i am trying to understand if the transactions have bits of nonce exposed or is it normal for it to be like that, so frankly i am no longer about WIF but signatures